# tapply function complains that args are unequal length yet they appear to match

Tags: r, tapply

Here is the failing call, error messages and some displays to show the lengths in question:

```
it <- tapply(molten, c(molten$Activity, molten$Subject, molten$variable), mean)
# Error in tapply(molten, c(molten$Activity, molten$Subject, molten$variable),  : 
#  arguments must have same length

length(molten$Activity)
# [1] 679734

length(molten$Subject)
# [1] 679734

length(molten$variable)
# [1] 679734

dim(molten)
# [1] 679734      4

str(molten)
# 'data.frame': 679734 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Activity: Factor w/ 6 levels "WALKING","WALKING_UPSTAIRS",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
#  $ Subject : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ variable: Factor w/ 66 levels "tBodyAcc-mean()-X",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ value   : num  0.257 0.286 0.275 0.27 0.275 ...
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a look at `?tapply` you will see that `X` should be "an atomic object, typically a vector". You feed `tapply` with a data frame ("molten"), which is not an atomic object. See `is.atomic`, and try `is.atomic(molten)`. Furthermore, your grouping variables should be provided as a `list` (see `INDEX` argument).

Something like this works:

```
tapply(X = warpbreaks$breaks,  INDEX = list(warpbreaks$wool, warpbreaks$tension), mean)
#          L        M        H
# A 44.55556 24.00000 24.55556
# B 28.22222 28.77778 18.77778
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a single object for INDEX, but`c( )`will string them all together which is the source of the eror, so use a list:

```
it <- tapply(molten$value, list(Act=molten$Activity, sub=molten$Subject, var=molten$variable), mean)
```

Better would be:

```
it <- with(molten , tapply(value, list(Act=Activity, Sub=Subject, var=variable), mean) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever got this solved? Because I had the same issue reading in a CSV file and could fix the issue by saving the original CSV file as CSV(delimiter seperated) instead of CSV(delimiter seperated-UTF-8). My dataset had German Umlauts in it though so that might play a role aswell.